# First item of database missing in list view while retrieving from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve list of snaps received from users(as emails) in a list view. Everything is working but the problem is that the **'First Item of data under the child 'Snaps Received' is not reflected in the list view.'**

Every entry subsequent to first one(From:kkg@gmail.com) is visible in the list...
but,

> - why not the first one?
> - and how to fix this?

[image]

Given below is code for my Activity(in Kotlin)

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

class SnapsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var snapsRecieved:ListView
    var snapsArray:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_snaps)

        snapsRecieved = findViewById(R.id.snapsRecievedLV)
        var arrayAdapter:ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,snapsArray)
        snapsRecieved.adapter = arrayAdapter

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).child("Snaps Recieved").addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {}
            override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {}

            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
               snapsArray.add(p0.child("From").value as String)
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {}

        })


    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the height and other attributes and make sure it is not being overlayed by something else

Comment: The list view is the only element I've in that activity frame, and its constrained well.

Comment: Pelase add the content of your .XML file. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Can you add a simple log statement to `onChildAdded` and see if that gets called the first child node?